# Giving bean id by spring annotation way

Tags: spring

Let's say I have a class.

```
@Service
public class SomeService {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void printHello() {
        System.out.println("Spring 3 : Hello ! " + name);
    }
}
```

The *someService* bean id is created for this bean by default. I want to change this bean id to say "abc". How would I do that ?

Comment: Don't name your beans, depend on types alone. Also, code as text, not image.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**@Service("abc")** will do the trick you want.

This will applicable for **any @Component annotation** such as @Service,@Repository and @Controller etc.

Comment: can i see bean id visually?